# Link thousands domains to a single Google App Engine app

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7, domain-mapping

We are developping a website builder using Google App Engine and Python 2.7

We need to link thousands of domains to a single Google App Engine bucket.

There is a solution in the docs but i fear we will encounter some restrictions after a certain amount of linked domains.
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/domain

Do you guys know an alternative ?

Thanks

Comment: What restrictions do you fear you will encounter? I'm not aware of any limits on how many domains are mapped.

Comment: I've read somewhere there was a limit of ~600 domains per app

Comment: There was indeed a limitation. Now one can use Google Cloud DNS and their API to automatically bind an unlimited amount of domain to a Google App Engine application : https://cloud.google.com/dns/